# Remove preceeding CRLF if the current line starts with a SPACE

Tags: c#, string, datatable

An example source I need to work with text file:

```
Analysis: this is a test that wraps
 and this is the second line
 this is the third line
Demonstration: This is an example of only one line
Result data more text
```

My expected output if all works:

| LineID | Source | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Analysis: this is a test that wraps and this is the second line this is the third line |  |
| 2 | Demonstration: This is an example of only one line |  |
| 3 | Result data more text |  |

This is my code that I want to add to the datagridview

```cs
string path = @"Sample1.txt";
dtSource.Columns.Add("LineID");
dtSource.Columns.Add("Source");
dtSource.Columns.Add("Description");
           
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
int linenum = 0;
foreach (string s in readText)
{
    string sourceline = s;
    if(sourceline.StartsWith(" "))
    {
        sourceline = sourceline.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""); //STUCK
    }
    dtSource.Rows.Add(linenum, sourceline, "");
    linenum++;
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dtSource;
```

Now I can't clearly think. Was thinking to just use a `List<string>` then manipulate but didn't want to add more stuff. Also, thought about just modifying the text from the previous datatable row joining the two. Any linq queries or something that I can do to simplify this?

Comment: `entire_text.Replace("\r\n ", " ")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
        foreach (string s in readText)
        {
            string sourceline = s;
            if (sourceline.StartsWith(" "))
            {
                dtSource.Rows[linenum - 1]["Source"] += sourceline;
            }
            else
            {
                dtSource.Rows.Add(linenum, sourceline, "");
                linenum++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Aggregate`

```
var result = readText.Aggregate(new List<string>(), (acc, x) =>
{
    if (x.StartsWith(" "))
    {
        acc[acc.Count - 1] += x;
    }
    else
    {
        acc.Add(x);
    }
    return acc;
}).Select((s, i) => dtSource.Rows.Add(i + 1, s, string.Empty)).ToList();
```